# prettify-symbols-mode text search requirements when combined with org-mode

Tags: org-mode, prettify-symbols-mode

In a `fundamental-mode` buffer, I run the following

```
(setq-local prettify-symbols-alist '(("\\(" . ?⟦)
                                     ("\\)" . ?⟧)))
```

The purpose of this is to render eg.:

- `\(a+b\)` -> `⟦a+b⟧`
- `a\(b, a\)b` -> `a⟦b, a⟧b`.

This works fine. Now if I switch into `org-mode` and do the same thing:

- `\(` -> `⟦`
- `\)` -> `⟧`
- `\(α+β\)` -> `⟦α+β\)`
- `a\(b, a\)b` -> `a\(b, a\)b`

The rendering is now dependent on the whitespace surrounding the `\(` and `\)`.
This is not desired behaviour.
I would like to make it behave the same in `org-mode` as it did in `fundamental-mode`.